# Fractions with $a < \sigma(b)$ are dense

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum

Prove that any open interval of real numbers in $[1, \infty)$ contains a rational number $\frac{a}{b}$, $(a,b)=1$, with $b\leq a < \sigma(b)$. (Here $\sigma$ denotes sum of all positive divisors.)

No idea how to start this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: If the open interval is $(C,D)$, then you're being asked to find relatively prime integers $a$ and $b$ such that $Cb<a<Db$ and $a<\sigma(b)$. It would apparently simplify the problem greatly if one could choose $b$ so that $\sigma(b)>Db$....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider an arbitrary open interval in $[1,\infty)$, say $(\alpha,\beta)$. We want:
$$\alpha < \frac{a}{b}<\beta$$
$$b < a < \sigma(b)$$
Thus, it suffices that we find $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha \cdot b < a < \beta \cdot b$, $\gcd(a,b)=1$, and $\sigma(b) > \beta \cdot b$, since we know:
$$\alpha \cdot b <a < \beta \cdot b < \sigma(b) \implies b < a < \sigma(b)$$
Can you complete the problem from here?